# Create unique index for existing node

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j batch inserter to import some data from a RDBMS. That data is processed, inserted and some nodes are cached to be uniquely indexed later. The thing is that, when using the `UniqueFactory`, the nodes are created again, resulting in duplicates. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Is there a way to create an unique index for an already existing node that isn't indexed? Preferably using the Java client calls?

Edit: here's the simplified code

```
BatchInserter inserter = BatchInserters.inserter(DB_PATH);
try {
    for (Person p : rdbms.getPersons()) {
        // Process data, modeling in graph form
        inserter.createNode(personProperties);
        Long cityId = inserter.createNode(cityProperties);
        cache.put(cityId, Type.CITY);
        // More nodes
        // Relationships (they aren't cached)
    }
} finally {
    inserter.shutdown();
}

GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
try {
    for (Entry<Long, Type> entry : cache.entrySet()) {
        Long nodeId = entry.getKey();
        Type nodeType = entry.getValue();
        UniqueFactory<Node> nodeFactory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory(
            db, nodeType.name().toLowerCase()) {
                @Override protected void initialize(
                        Node created, Map<String, Object> properties) {
                    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
                        created.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
            };
        Node nodeToIndex = db.getNodeById(nodeId);
        Entry<String, Object> nameAndValue 
                = getIndexedPropertyNameAndValue(nodeType, node);
        nodeFactory.getOrCreate(nameAndValue.getKey(), nameAndValue.getValue());
    }
} finally {
    db.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code ? Are you using the REST interface ?

Comment: Done. No, I'm using the Java client.